# Empty div with 2px width and background color doesnt show with height as 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 columns  and first and third column are divided by a vertical line for which i used table with with 100% height and background color which works in fine in FF but doesn't work in Chrome or IE.

Now i replace the table with div tag but empty div doesn't show up. Below is the sample code i tried so many thing now i am confused what to use. Need help from CSS Gurus.

```
 .PageLine2V
    {
        width:2px;
        content: "";
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color:#D1C094;
        background-image:url('../images/gold-line-2v.gif'); 
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
    }
<table height="100%">
        <td width="60px" valign="top" align="center" >
         <div class="PageLine2V"></div>
        </td>
</table>
```

I am not sure how i can make this empty  div show up and grow with table height also

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 .PageLine2V
    {
        width:2px;
        content: "";
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color:#D1C094;
        background-image:url('../images/gold-line-2v.gif'); 
        background-repeat:repeat-y;
        height: 100%;

    }
```

Give the div a height of 100%

Also add something in the div such as a space it won't render without content.

```
<table height="100%">
        <td width="60px" valign="top" align="center" >
         <div class="PageLine2V">&nbsp;</div>
        </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Problem was with the parent table as i have not mentioned height=100% it now works fine and show up correctly in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

Setting height to 100% requires that the parent have an explicitly defined height. Add `height: 100%` to the td (the parent of the div). Tested and working with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
.PageLine2V
{
    width:2px;
    content: "";
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color:#D1C094;
    background-image:url('../images/gold-line-2v.gif'); 
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    height: 35px; /* As required */
    display:inline-block;

}
```

Hope this will work. As I tried, I've used the same code with a fixed height in pixels and added `display:inline-block;`. Next you may try adjusting the parent height parameters for further positioning.

Answer (score -1):

give it a position:absolute;
http://jsfiddle.net/eg6DP/

you can see it on the far left,and while you're at it give the table a position as well.

Comment: It is not showing up in when i use it with my web page i have to investigate may be it is overlapping pr something like that.. Problem is that when i put any character in the div tag it show the line but when it is empty it doesn't..

Comment: add a space in side the tag: <div> </div>