# Are we supposed to be able to trust empty DIVs to show in HTML5?

Tags: html, css

Having seen advice seemingly change over the years regarding use of empty DIVs (ie. `<DIV CLASS="somediv"></DIV>`) I'm confused as to the current thinking over whether or not to use `&nbsp;` when a DIV will have no inner HTML.

I can find no definitive confirmation over whether we can rely on all modern browsers to display background color and image correctly at the specified width & height when there is no inner HTML, so I'm thinking maybe we can't rely on it - yet it's such a seemingly basic area.

I have even seen suggestions that empty DIVs should never be used - but do specs really state it is 'wrong' to have empty DIVs, or is it just unreliable? (I've tried finding reference to them, but maybe I'm using the wrong terms).

To illustrate, here are 5 areas where I would normally use an empty DIV, in the absence of any recommended alternative:

1. as a placeholder for content which will subsequently be fetched by XHR calls
2. as a way to manually create space in a layout
3. where an image is defined in CSS (as a background image, but will effectively be foreground)
4. where the text will come from the CSS using `.somediv:after{content:SOMETEXT}`
5. where CSS is used to display graph bars etc using solid background color

Maybe there are different answers for each of these, which might explain the complexity over this issue.

I have, of course, tried discovering already, but for example the SO question [Is necessary to show an empty <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198058/is-necessary-to-show-an-empty-div) suggests to me there is a huge amount of "IMHO", "probably", "seems to work" in this area. I would expect that by now that some official consensus has been reached on best practice.

So.. should I use `&nbsp;` and if so should I set font-size to the same as the smaller of DIV width/height to ensure that space is filled in all browsers? Are there any other CSS tricks to ensure this will work in all browsers?

Comment: Of course you can rely on that, an empty element is still an element in the DOM and can be formated.

Comment: Can you find any evidence, anywhere, that a hack for inconsistent browser support for whether or not to show empty **`td` elements** has *any* relevance to `div`?

Comment: What specs say and browsers do are (most sadly) very seperate things.  According to the (CSS) specs, there should be no difference between empty and non-empty elements with regards to the background property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser is not going to discard or forget your container just because it does not have any contents (yet).

If you want the container to have a specific placeholder shape, then you might give it `min-height`, `min-width`, `height` and `width` and make sure it's `display: block;`.

If you are still unsure, you can fill it with a `spacer.gif/png` without padding and margin.

http://jsfiddle.net/APxNF/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer - just to clarify, would you put that spacer in an IMG tag?

I havebeen encouraged to put display images on a page as a background-image in a DIV, rather than in IMG tag so it does seem ironic I would then use an IMG for a part I can't see. Now I'm thinking maybe there are times when it's best to just use a good old-fashioned IMG in the first place?!

Comment: The difference is, that background images or non-blocking, and `img`'s are blocking. A `div`won't stretch if you give it more `height` (than it's content actually has), except you put `min-height` in it or put a blocking, invisible `img` inside of it.

Comment: I put examples in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Short answer. Yes, browsers will render the div even if there is no content.

Long answer, That *might* now always be the case. I have worked in the web for 8 years now and never had to use these, but here they are anyway.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bPBSr/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="empty1"></div>
<div class="empty2"></div>
<div class="empty3"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.empty1 {
    background: #FBB829;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.empty2:before {
    content: "\00a0";
}
.empty2 {
    background: #FF0066;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.empty3 {
    background: #F02311;
    min-height: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Sources:

- Experience
- [Empty div with 2px width and background color doesnt show with height as 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135032/empty-div-with-2px-width-and-background-color-doesnt-show-with-height-as-100)
- http://csscreator.com/node/36023

Comment: Thanks for you answer - just to clarify, when you say you've never had to use them do you mean you never use empty DIVs, or never had to use the example code in order to make empty DIVs display? Thanks.